# Losing my playback window handle/primary surface in directshow?

Tags: wpf, directshow

I am using WPF and Directshowlib to render video to a HWndHost object. I'm having two problems with this, probably related.

If I start up my application and then switch to another app running fullscreen, e.g. World of Warcraft, the application returns an error when calling IVMRFilterConfig::SetRenderingMode(VMRMode.Windowless);:

0x887600E1, DDERR_NOEXCLUSIVEMODE, Operation requires the application to have exclusive mode but the application does not have exclusive mode.

In other circumstances, when the video window is fine and video playing back, if I cause a UAC Dialog by, for example, starting another application as Administrator or if I lock the screen I also lose the playback window. My video rendering window goes grey and video playback just stops (I get no media ended events any more). I get no error, just a grey rendering window.

What can I do to ensure I get and keep a video window in both these circumstances? Why am I losing the video window anyway?

Thanks!